# Not getting all rows from a query with odbc_exec in php

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I'm trying to display how many id's does my procedure finds, but the variable $processz only got the first row of the sql result. It should display that there are 17 rows or id's, and only got 1. Why does it happends?

```
  $conexion = con_abrir();

  $sqlquery = "OEE.dbo.VerPlanillas_fechas '$Linea_ID','$fecha1','$fecha2'";
  $processz = odbc_exec($conexion,$sqlquery);

  con_cerrar($conexion); 

  $res = count($processz);
  echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0):

count ($processz) tells you how many results you have - one.

If you want to know how many rows are in the result, you need to call odbc_num_rows ($processz);

Look into using PDO rather than odbc specific functions.

Comment: It's still getting just 1 row as result using odbc_num_rows. Could it be a problem of executing the query with odbc_exec?

Comment: You're not fetching them from a table, you're fetching a row of 3 strings that happen to be column names in a table. What happens when you SELECT column_name_1, columns_name_2, column_name_3 FROM table_name and then dump the actual rows?